Calling an API to test in .NET Core with webhost factory http client throws 404 error
Description: I'm working on setting up integration tests for my ASP.NET Core application using WebHostFactory. I've configured a test server with custom authentication and an in-memory database, but when I call my API endpoint in the test, I get a "404 Not Found" error.
Here are the relevant parts of my setup - test setup:
public class MyIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyIntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _client = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
             {
                 builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                     {
                         var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));
                         services.Remove(descriptor);

                         services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                             {
                                 options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                             });

                         services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                             .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("Test", options => { });
                     });

        builder.Configure(app =>
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseMiddleware<MockAuthenticationMiddleware>();
        });
    })
    .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    });

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");
    }
}

I have this simple controller to test the POC inside my web server project:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetToday")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new { Weather = "Sunny" });
    }
}

When I try to call it in this function, it gives me 404 not found. (Please note that previously it was giving me a 401 not authorized error which I got solved by mocking the authentication) However, this, I can't seem to overcome.
[Given("the second number is (.*)")]
public async Task GivenTheSecondNumberIs(int number)
{
    _response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/WeatherForecast/GetToday");
    _response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var content = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Assert.True(_response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
}


The route is not found or you do not have permission to read the route.   The route can be a separate HTML file on server with different permissions than the controller.

I added the tag [AllowAnonymous] what do you think I should do? The WebServer is a seperate project which contains the controllers. I added a reference to it in the testsproject

Anonymous is a login without credentials.  You have credentials.  Are all the routes failing?  Does "api/[controller]" work?  You do not have controller in following : "/api/WeatherForecast/GetToday".  Most likely you are getting an exception in the controller which is returning 404.  You need to find where the exception is occurring.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464540/returning-a-404-from-an-explicitly-typed-asp-net-core-api-controller-not-iactio

Hi @jdweng it also didn't work when I put it like this [Route("api/WeatherForecast")]
how can I test if the test server apis are working? this is the most basic controller I want to make a poc with

Add break point into server and see where you are getting.  You can also use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to see if server is listening to the port and the status of the listener.  You can add filters to server to help isolate issues : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#registering-exception-filters

Ok so after adding services.AddControllers()
.AddApplicationPart(typeof(WeatherForecastController).Assembly); this line I am getting 401 unauthorized

You must have [Authorize] and then need to give each route a user or role to allow access.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute
